# how can I improve my traning and validation accuracies?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, image-recognition, resnet

I juste trained 3d Resnet50 model on my dataset (I am using the MSR Daily activity 3D which consist of 16 actions and which is relatively a small dataset) and to get better results I traind it using a pretrained model from the kinetics-700 dataset(I used transfer learning) After the training I got training accuracy = 0.88 and validation accuracy = 0.52 Is there any other ideas to further improve these result ! Or due to the small dataset is that the best that I can get !

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404075/how-should-we-handle-machine-learning-questions-asking-for-performance-improveme/

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the overall performance via 2 major methods. Most of the times people give least important to the second one. They are,

1. Model Centric AI
2. Data Centric AI

### 1. Model Centric AI

In Model Centric AI, we try to find the right parameter for the model according to our dataset (i.e Tuning the hyperparameter). For this cause we could use several libraries such as `optuna`, `keras tuner`, `Azure Hyperdrive` and lot more.

By this way we can figure out the right paramters to fit with.

### 2. Data Centric AI

> Garbage in Garbage out

The main idea is to have a good and clean dataset. Although you are using readily availble datasets, not everytime they ensure quality. So it is always a good practice to ensure the quality of the dataset we prefer to train our model.

*- - - It is not about the size of dataset, it is all about the quality of the data we use.*

From the `World's Top University` - Here is a beautiful course focused on [Data Centric AI](https://dcai.csail.mit.edu)

In terms of `Computer Vision` data, I find this library outperforms - [Clean Lab](https://github.com/cleanlab/cleanlab)

Feel free to reach out to me! Happy Coding!